# Having trouble with the output of this combination in Java

Tags: java, combinations

I'm trying to calculate a combination using this formula: [image: formula]

I'm running into issues with the output. My program simply outputs 0 when I run this code:

```
public class Lottery {
    public static long numPossibleTickets(int k, int n, int m) {
        int i;
        int j;
        long numerator = n;
        long denominator = k;
        long total = 0;
        for (i = n - 1; i > (k + 1); i--) {
            numerator = numerator * i;
        }
        i = 0;
        for (j = k; j > 0; j--) {
            denominator = denominator * (denominator - i);
            i++;
        }
        total = m * (numerator / denominator);
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = 5;
        int n = 69;
        int m = 26;
   System.out.println(numPossibleTickets(k, n, m));
    }
}
```

However, the output should be 292,201,338. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps you should be using long values inside this function?

Comment: Isn't what you are dividing resulting in zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to create a method to get the factorial of a number.
besides also using a `BigInteger` as long isn't enough to store big numbers factorial
so here's final code and it's working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int k = 5;
    int n = 69;
    int m = 26;
    System.out.println(numPossibleTickets(k, n, m)); // result is 292201338
}
public static BigInteger numPossibleTickets(int k, int n, int m) {
    int i;
    int j;
    BigInteger numerator =  getFactorial(n);
    BigInteger denominator = getFactorial(k).multiply(getFactorial(n-k));
    BigInteger total ;

    total = new BigInteger(m+"").multiply(numerator.divide(denominator));
    return total;
}

// to get the factorial of given number 
public static BigInteger getFactorial(int number){
    BigInteger factorial = new BigInteger(number+"");
    for (int i = number - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(new BigInteger(i+""));
    }
    return  factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 different problems with your code.

You are trying to compute the number of combinations using factorials. The problem with factorial is that it grows incredibly fast: the intermediate results don't fit in the range for the `long` data type, and the result is useless. You could use the `BigInteger` for the computations, but it won't be particularly efficient. With that change:

```
public static long numPossibleTickets(int k, int n, int m) {
    int i;
    int j;
    BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.valueOf(k);
    long total = 0;
    for (i = n - 1; i > (k + 1); i--) {
        numerator = numerator.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    i = 0;
    for (j = k; j > 0; j--) {
        denominator = denominator.multiply(denominator.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(i)));
        i++;
    }
    total = m * numerator.divide(denominator).longValue();
    return total;
}
```

Second, the loop that computes the numerator is off by one: instead of computing 69!/5! it's computing 69!/6!. Luckily that's easy to fix:

```
    for (i = n - 1; i >= (k + 1); i--) {
        numerator = numerator.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Third, the loop that computes the denominator seems to be way off. I don't know what you're trying to do, but given what you are computating for the numerator, the denominator should be computing (n-k)!, and that could look like this:

```
    BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int j = n-k; j > 1; j--) {
        denominator = denominator.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
    }
```

With these three changes, I get the expected output `292201338`.